# Amazon RDS CPU is about 55-65% after optimizing some Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I was having high RAM consumption and, looking for a solution, I executed the script mysqltunner to monitor possible optimizations in the Mysql database. Its first advice was I had to run

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE tablename;
```

So as, I had about 40 tables to optimize I ran it with the following php script:

```
<?php

    // connect your database here first 

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database"); 

    if($mysqli){
        echo "Connexion established";
    }else{
        echo "Imposible to establish a connexion to the database";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'";

    $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            $tbl = $row[0];
            $sql = "OPTIMIZE TABLE `$tbl`";
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    echo "Optimization finished";

?>
```

And when it finished the execution I saw that 600Mb of RAM had been liberated. However, the CPU went from 5% of usage to 55%.

I connected to the database and ran

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

receiving this output

```
+-------+----------+---------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id    | User     | Host                | db    | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+-------+----------+---------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
|  1020 | rdsadmin | localhost:39883     | mysql | Sleep   |    3 |       | NULL             |
| 60204 | user     | 172.31.11.223:40268 | NULL  | Query   |    0 | init  | show processlist |
+-------+----------+---------------------+-------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

The process 1020 of user rdsadmin is all the time there, I suppose it must be there. But apparently there are no threads to have so much CPU in use...

Do you have an idea of what can be happening and possible fixes?

Thank you!

Comment: So .... - did you bother checking out what process uses 55%?

Comment: Yes I tried, but as a RDS user I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me has been to restart the instance through the AWS console and everything is working now as expected. The instance consumes 0-10% of CPU most of the time and the RAM memory is using around 1Gb less than before.